# How to split some numbers and math operator in PHP?

Tags: php, string, function

I'm trying to create function which accepts a string (contains simple math expression) then splits each of the parts as an array.

For example the input is `2 + 3 * 7` or `2 – 5 / 3.4`, the output should be like `["2", "+", "3", "*", "7"]` and `["2", "-", "5", "/", "3.4"]`

Here are my codes:

```
$input = "2 + 3 * 7";
$input = "2-5/3.4";

function splitExpression($string) {
    $result = explode (" ", $input);
    print_r ($result);
}
```

Using only explode, of course the 1st example works nicely, but not the same with the other.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trying to split a string in 3 variables, but a little more tricky - PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4382163/trying-to-split-a-string-in-3-variables-but-a-little-more-tricky-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try like this - [based upon answer elsewhere on stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4382163/trying-to-split-a-string-in-3-variables-but-a-little-more-tricky-php). Modified the pattern and added the preg_replace so that the results are not affected by spaces in the input string.

```
$input = '2 + 3 * 7';
$input = '2-5/3.4';


$pttn='@([-/+\*])@';
$out=preg_split( $pttn, preg_replace( '@\s@', '', $input ), -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE );

printf('<pre>%s</pre>',print_r( $out, true ) );
```

Will output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => -
    [2] => 5
    [3] => /
    [4] => 3.4
)
```

**Update:**

```
$input = '2 + 5 - 4 / 2.6';


$pttn='+-/*';   # standard mathematical operators
$pttn=sprintf( '@([%s])@', preg_quote( $pttn ) ); # an escaped/quoted pattern

$out=preg_split( $pttn, preg_replace( '@\s@', '', $input ), -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE );

printf('<pre>%s</pre>',print_r( $out, true ) );
```

outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => +
    [2] => 5
    [3] => -
    [4] => 4
    [5] => /
    [6] => 2.6
)
```

Comment: do you mean as in the "BODMAS" rule?

Comment: no, I don't believe it will - but then that was not part of the question and would, in fact, warrant a whole new question

Comment: Above question is not solved by your answer because  - first it calculate 2-5 and then division ...

Comment: take a look at the question - notably `"The output should be like ....."`

Comment: @RamRaider can you explain more to me about the `$pttn='@([-/+\*])@';` as a limiter? Cause when I change/reorder it, the output changes.

Comment: I think initially when I wrote that I got lucky 1st time around as when I changed the order it produced errors rather than a different order - due I'm sure to not escaping certain elements in the pattern. I'll add a modified snippet above that correctly escapes the mathematical operators

Answer (score 1):

you can use a regex:

```
$matches = array();
$input="2 + 3 * 7 / 5 - 3";
preg_match_all("/\d+|[\\+\\-\\/\\*]/",$input,$matches);
```

this regex searches for a number or an operator and puts the matches into $matches.
you can edit the design of the matches array by flags.

```
matches:
 + 0
     - 0 : 2
     - 1 : +
     - 2 : 3
     - 3 : *
     - 4 : 7
     - 5 : /
     - 6 : 5
     - 7 : -
     - 8 : 3
```

Comment: That regex is invalid.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [str_split()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php) for it. Like
`str_split($str1);`

```
$input = "2-5/3.4";
$input = "2 + 3 * 7";

function splitExpression($string) {
    //$result = str_split (string);
    $result = str_split (preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $string));
    return $result;
}
$arr1 = splitExpression($input);
```

Where `preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $string)` used to remove white space from string.

Comment: What if the string is `30 + 4 *2`? Or `40+3.4`? Or the first of the `$input`? This doesn't really work. This will only work when there are integers, no decimals, and no number greater than 9. Quite the heavy restriction.